# Auth - keeps login out

Tags: laravel-5

I keep getting logged out whilst using the system. What common issues should I be looking for?

Within laravel authentication sessions should last for 15 minutes.

The only issue that I can see is that I was logged out due to me performing some AJAX requests on the system which may have caused authentication token to change?

I am using default authentication library that comes with Laravel 5.2

Comment: 1. Check if you are sending the correct auth token with the AJAX calls. 2. Check the same AJAX call with all it's headers and data using PostMan and see if it still logs out.

Comment: The problem that I have is that logouts are very random. Hard to trigger again.